# You are not authorized to access this page. while trying to connect with an admin employee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, cancancan

Everytime i try to connect to my backoffice with an admin, I get this You are not authorized to access this page. even tho everything is setup to be supposed to accept admins. I've checked and all my employees are admins so it shouldn't be doing this!

I've tried to restrain basic users rights, I've tried accessing the page with every account but I always get this error, even tho all the employees are admins!

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(employee)
  employee ||= Employee.new # guest employee (not logged in)
  if employee.admin?
    can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin employees to access Rails Admin
    can :read, :dashboard
    can :manage, :all
    authorize!(:dashboard, @employee)
  end
end
end
```

employees_controller.rb

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    def employee_params
        params.require(:employee).permit(:email, :encrypted_password, :password_confirmation, :role)
      end
end
```

accessible.rb

```
module Accessible
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      before_action :check_employee
    end

    protected
    def check_employee
      if current_employee.admin
        flash.clear
        redirect_to(rails_admin.dashboard_path) && return
      elsif current_employee
        flash.clear
        redirect_to(new_employee_session_path) && return
      end
    end
  end
```

rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  config.parent_controller = "::ApplicationController"

  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    if current_employee.admin?
      redirect_to main_app.new_account_session_path, flash: {error: 'Please Login to Continue..'}
    elsif !current_employee.admin?
      redirect_to main_app.root_path, flash: {error: 'You are not Admin'}
    end
  end


  ## == CancanCan ==
  config.authorize_with :cancancan

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users, path: 'users'

devise_for :employees, path: 'employee'

  namespace :user do
    resources :users
  end

  namespace :employee do
    resources :employees
  end

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

  root 'index#Index'

  get '/Index', to: 'index#Index'

  get '/ResidentialServices', to: 'pages#ResidentialServices'

  get '/CorporateServices', to: 'pages#CorporateServices'

  get '/Quotes', to: 'pages#Quotes'

  get '/Awards', to: 'pages#Awards'

end
```

add admin to employees migration

```
class AddAdminToEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :employees, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

employee (you can see that I've set my admin to true :

```
Employee.create!(lastName: 'xxx', firstName: 'xxx', title: 'Comm Rep', email: 'xxx@xx.xx', encrypted_password: BCrypt::Password.create('123456'), admin: 'true')
```

i expect admins to be able to access the backoffice

Comment: cancancan expects a `current_user` helper method, not a `current_employee` helper method - I'm guessing this is the helper method that you are using (if you have utilised the `devise` gem). You can check whether the employee you are passing into the ability method has been initialised using a debugger like `byebug` - my guess it that it has not been initialised at all. In short, you need to tell `cancancan` that you are using `current_employee` and not 'current_user`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you pass variable instead of instance variable in ability.rb?

```
authorize!(:dashboard, employee)
```

instead of

```
authorize!(:dashboard, @employee)
```

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately, I've been trying to fix this for the last 3h

Answer (score 0):

#### cancancan expects a current_user not a current_employee

cancancan expects a `current_user` helper method, not a `current_employee` helper method - I'm guessing this is the helper method that you presently have, if you are using the devise gem.

You can check whether the employee you are passing into the ability method has been initialised using a debugger like byebug - my guess it that it has not been initialised at all. In short, you need to tell cancancan that you are using `current_employee` and not `current_user`

Here is a quick hack that should do that for you:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  alias_method :current_user, :current_employee
end
```